# (Core dumped) Linked Lists in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, coredump

I am trying to write a simple program to store integer values in a 3 node linked list but it says "Segmentation fault (core dumped )" after I insert the first value.

I am relatively new to c++ so i don't really know what I'm doing wrong. I've tried researching on the Internet for solutions but i can't seem to find any.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node{
   int num;
   node *next;
};
node *head=NULL;
node *tail=NULL; 
void create(int num){
   node *temp=new node;
   temp->num=num;
   temp->next=NULL;
   if(head=NULL){
      head=temp;
      tail=temp;
      temp=NULL;
   }
   else{
      tail->next=temp;
      tail=temp;
   }
}

void display(node *current ){
    while(current!=NULL){
         cout<<current->num<<endl;
         current=current->next;
    }
}

int main(){

   int num;
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
       cout<<"Enter a number:";
       cin>>num;

   }
   display(head);
   return 0;
 }
```

Any help and/or tips is appreciated :)

Edit: Ok so I saw i missed that int he if clause head is supposed to be head==NULL,but now it doesn't display the linked list at the end :(

Comment: `head=NULL` should be `head == NULL`

Comment: To be precise `if(head=NULL){` should be `if (head == NULL) {`, `node *head=NULL;` is ok. Easier to see this kind of mistake if you use a few spaces when you layout your code?

Comment: FYI, since c++11 you should use `nullptr` and not `NULL`, and also since c++11 you should not use `new` or `delete` anymore but use smart pointers for object creation and to handle ownership of an object.

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to single step through your code, watching values in variables.  Often, using a debugger is a lot faster than correctly posting to StackOverflow and waiting for somebody to inspect or debug your program for you.

Answer (score 1):

Changed head=NULL to head==NULL in if statement. and please call create function inside for loop. Here is my solution:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node {
    int num;
    node *next;
};
node *head = NULL;
node *tail = NULL;
void create(int num) {
    node *temp = new node;
    temp->num = num;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
        temp = NULL;
    }
    else {
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
}

void display(node *current) {
    while (current != NULL) {
        cout << current->num << endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}

int main() {

    int num;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "Enter a number:";
        cin >> num;
        create(num);
    }
    display(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I feel so stupid for making some basic errors in my coding. I'll be sure to be more careful next time :)